# Strange error after getting Value from Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I crated  SelectList selectList with data from my Entities.
And now I want send value from DropDownList to Entitie.
everything is OK (I got value from selected item) , but I got his error et the end

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: **There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Przelew.DaneKont'**.*

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Przelew.DaneKont", ViewBag.DaneKontList as SelectList, "-- Wybierz kontot --")
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Przelew.DaneKont", ViewBag.DaneKontList as SelectList, "-- Wybierz kontot --")
```

**Controller:**

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult WykonajPrzelew( ) {



            using (var context = new BankAppEntities1())
            {
                konto = context.Konto.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Konto WHERE UserId = '" + userIdValue + "' ").ToList();

            }


            WykonajPrzelewMultipleView mymodel = new WykonajPrzelewMultipleView();
            mymodel.Konta = konto;

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();


            foreach (var item in konto){

                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nazwa+ "  Saldo :"+item.Saldo , Value = item.KontoId+"" });

             }

            ViewBag.DaneKont = items;

            SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
            ViewBag.DaneKontList = selectList;




            return View(mymodel);
        }


      [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WykonajPrzelew(WykonajPrzelewMultipleView model)
        {



            string imie = model.Przelew.ImieOdbiorcy;
            string nazwisko = model.Przelew.NazwiskoOdbiorcy;
            int numerOdbiorcy = Convert.ToInt32(model.Przelew.NumerRachunkuOdbiorcy);
            int kontoID = Convert.ToInt32(model.Przelew.DaneKont); // I got Value from List 

            string tytul = model.Przelew.Tytuł;
            string ulica = model.Przelew.Ulica;
            string numerdomu = model.Przelew.nrdomu;
            string kod = model.Przelew.Kodpocztowy;
            string miasto = model.Przelew.Miasto;
       string tyt =model.Przelew.Tytuł;
            decimal kwota = model.Przelew.Kwota;
            DateTime date = System.DateTime.Now;



            using (var context2 = new BankAppEntities1())
            {
                var dane = new Przelew { Imie = imie, Nazwisko = nazwisko, NumerKontaOdbiorcy = numerOdbiorcy, KontoId = "1", NumerKontaNadawcy = 3444666, Ulica = ulica, Nr_domu = numerdomu,Kod_pocztowy="343", Miasto = miasto, Typ = "Normlany", UserId = userIdValue,Kwota=kwota , Date=date , Tytul=tyt };
                context2.Przelew.Add(dane);

                context2.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another property on your model such as `DaneKont`, and change your view to the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DaneKont", (SelectList)ViewBag.DaneKontList, "-- Wybierz kontot --")
```

On postback, `DaneKont` will hold the selected value.

Comment: I changed i to@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>Model.Przelew.DaneKont, (SelectList)ViewBag.DaneKontList, "-- Wybierz kontot --") its working now ( I got the value)but I got this error                                                                                          _There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Przelew.DaneKont'._ ;_;

Comment: the select list will not be populated on postback.  You will have to reload it or, better yet, just reload the item for the value that was posted back.

Comment: right now you are building them in your `GET` method. You should refactor that so you can reliably get the same values on POST.  1) verify the value passed in is allowed. 2) if you need the select list item, build it similarly to this: foreach (var item in konto){

                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nazwa+ "  Saldo :"+item.Saldo , Value = item.KontoId+"" });

             }

Comment: I don't see where you were ever using this value in your `POST` method.  If you update your question, I can update my answer with sample code.